# R function(s) create file that can't be deleted: "The operation can’t be completed because a required item is in use."

Tags: r, macos, terminal

First off, I apologize in advance that I don't know how to provide a reproducible example, because I'm not sure what is even causing this problem. I will provide as much detail as possible. I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.7, using R 4.1.0, and RStudio 1.4.1717.

I'm using a set of custom R functions and scripts, some of which involve creating and writing to logfiles, almost always logfile.txt or something of that sort. The scripts include the following line before any writing to delete any old logfiles:

```
system("touch logfile.txt; rm logfile.txt")
```

The outputs are written using commands of the structure:

```
system(paste0('echo \"Some output ', variable, ' here\" >> logfile.txt'))
```

Finally, one of the scripts uses the flock package to prevent simultaneous writing in certain parallelized sections:

```
intro.lock = flock::lock("logfile1.txt")
```

Which is then unlocked 2 lines later after writing output:

```
flock::unlock(intro.lock)
```

My problem is that most of the time, these logfiles created are IMPOSSIBLE to delete, even the ones that don't use flock. Whenever I try deleting them, I get the error: "The operation can’t be completed because a required item is in use." See image here:[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9yQP.png)

Steps I have tried:

- Quitting RStudio and all other apps that might be using the file
- Deleting the file via terminal with `[sudo] rm logfile.txt`. I get `rm: logfile.txt: Resource busy`
- Running `system(paste0("chflags -R nouchg,noschg logfile.txt"))` in each script that makes a logfile
- Using "Get Info" to see if the file is locked (none of them are)
- Checking `lsof +D ./` for any processes using these files. None appear to be.

The only solution I know of that makes these files able to be deleted is to restart my entire computer. After a restart, they are deletable using any method, even just dragging to the trash.

Any possible solutions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but in one of my scripts I use the following to clean up specific files that are 'left behind' at the end of the run:

```
rm(list = ls())
gc()
system("rm -R /tmp/Rtmp*")
system("rm -R /tmp/lib*.so")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly this gives the same result as just running "rm" in terminal; namely, `rm: logfile.txt: Resource busy`